# Relationship between motivic Galois groups and Langlands program

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, motives, langlands-conjectures

I would like to know if there is any relationship between the **motivic Galois groups** and the **Langlands program**.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think the paper of [Clozel, Motifs et formes automorphes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ty245/camonly/Clozel_Motifs.pdf) has something to do with this, but I've not readed the paper...

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/74698/6518 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/71743/6518 - have you tried looking at the papers mentioned in the latter?

Comment: **Langlands' Taniyama group is isomorphic to the Motivic galois group of the category of absolute hodge cycle CM motives over Q.** _Deligne, Hodge cycles, motives, and shimura varieties._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $K=\mathbb{Q}$ for simplicity, but this applies to any number field $K$, and let $L$ be the Langlands group and $\mathcal{G}$ the motivic Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then the conjectural relation between automorphic forms and motives (the Langlands program) implies that there is an homomorphism (up to a certain conjugation) such that the diagram

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
L @>{}>> \mathcal{G};\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) @>{}>>\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q});
\end{CD}$$

is commutative.

To get a better idea of both sides of this picture it is useful to use some classic (and better understood) intermediate groups. Let $W$ be the Weil group, $\mathcal{S}$ the Serre group and $\mathcal{T}$ the Taniyama group, then we have something like this

$$L \longrightarrow W \longrightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(automorphic side)}$$

$$\mathcal{G} \longrightarrow \mathcal{S} \longrightarrow \mathcal{T} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(motivic side)}$$

Most of this goes back to

- Robert Langlands, "[Automorphic representations, Shimura varieties and motives](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/autoreps-ps.pdf)" (1977)

Some other relevant references are

- James Milne, Kuang-yen Shih, "[Langlands's Construction of the Taniyama Group](http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1982c.pdf)" (1982)
- Norbert Schappacher, "[CM motives and the Taniyama group](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~schappa/NSch/Publications_files/1994a_TaniyamaGrp.pdf)" (1994)
- James Arthur, "[A note on the automorphic Langlands group](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/arthur/pdf/automorphic-langlands-group.pdf)" (2002)